# Instalación de font-awesome en laravel, algunos iconos se ven otros no

Tags: html, npm, font-awesome

Tengo un proyecto laravel y he instalado font-awesome de esta manera

```
npm install font-awesome --save
```

Luego he añadido esto en el fichero "resources/assets/saas/app.scss."

```
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";
```

Ahora si voy a una plantilla blade y pongo este código para mostrar este icono , **si funciona**

```
<i class="fa fa-search fa-2x"></i>
```

En cambio si pongo este otro código que es un "fas" no me muestra el icono

```
<i class="fas fa-comment-medical"></i>
```

Donde esta el fallo?
Gracias

Comment: ¿Que versión font-awesome instalaste?

Comment: Por lo que veo en el package.json --> "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",

Comment: En esa [versión no estaban disponibles esos iconos](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/). Si quieres usar esos [instala la versión 5 o 6](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers)

Comment: Gracias ya lo he solucionado, siguiendo las indicaciones de @porloscerros. 1000 gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjunto la solución, gracias a @porloscerros por la ayuda prestada.

Paso 1 - Modificar el package.json

```
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.8",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid": "^5.0.13",
```

Paso 2- Modificar fichero app.scss

```
//@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";

@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
```

Comment: Hola. Deberías marcar esta respuesta como la solución a tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias , @Néstor en 22h me deja hacerlo :)